# Show only objects with the latest date

Tags: views

How can I show objects having the latest post date? I.e. if 1 was posted yesterday, and 2 -- today, then show only 2 but if they both were posted yesterday and all the others before that, then show 1 and 2.

Is it possible with Views?

Comment: or, in other words, show only first group of display if using grouping criteria on post date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's logic involved (check records based on this date, if there are no results, check the previous date) I would do this with a custom module making use of [Entity Field Queries](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).